# Data incollapsible rows

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatable, row

I have a little problem with my code. I want to be able to display in when you click on each line to display data specific to the line clicked according to the information that my request gives me. But the same information is repeated the same number of times when I paste a line. I recover the data thanks to PDO of php and I table thanks to html and javascript.

This is my HTML/PHP code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>jQuery Bootstrap Table Expandable Demo</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- INCLUDES -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap-table-expandable.css">
<script src="../js/bootstrap-table-expandable.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="jquery-script-menu">
<div class="jquery-script-center">
<div class="jquery-script-ads"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2783044520727903";
/* jQuery_demo */
google_ad_slot = "2780937993";
google_ad_width = 728;
google_ad_height = 90;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
<div class="jquery-script-clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 style="margin-top:150px;">Activité des commerciaux</h1>
  <table class="table table-hover table-expandable table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>MSISDN</th>
        <th>NICKNAME</th>
        <th>Type de compte</th>
        <th>Nom du commercial</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach($resultcomm as $com){?>

      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $com['POS_MSIDSN'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $com['POS_NICKCNAME'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $com['POS_ACCOUNTYPE'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $com['NOM_COMMERCIAL'] ?></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
          <h4>Additional information ok</h4>

        <?php foreach($resultCollapsed as $comd){?>

      <ul>
            <li><?php echo "Points de ventes attribués".$comd['pdv'] ?></li>
      </ul> 

      <?php } ?>

        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <?php } ?>
</tbody>
    
  </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my Javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    $(function () {
        $('.table-expandable').each(function () {
            var table = $(this);
            table.children('thead').children('tr').append('<th></th>');
            table.children('tbody').children('tr').filter(':odd').hide();
            table.children('tbody').children('tr').filter(':even').click(function () {
                var element = $(this);
                element.next('tr').toggle('slow');
                element.find(".table-expandable-arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
            table.children('tbody').children('tr').filter(':even').each(function () {
                var element = $(this);
                element.append('<td><div class="table-expandable-arrow"></div></td>');
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here's the problem

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried var_dump($resultCollapsed); to see if the array actually contains the data you're expecting? It's possible you're accessing just the first element of a multidimensional array or your PHP query is only return the result from one call, possibly using fetch() instead of fetchAll().

Could you also share with us where the information for $resultCollapsed is coming from and how it's being obtained.

Could you post additional info of what var_dump($resultCollapsed); contains?

To help, You can just copy the code below into your page, right before the closing  tag and run that.

```
<?php 
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($resultCollapsed);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

this should dump the contents of $resultCollapsed as a nicely formatted string to the bottom of your page. If you could then show us what that looks like, we can offer more help.

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you for your indications, they helped me a lot and I was able to solve my problem. Thanks !